# where does the android emulator store files created using org.apache.cordova.file

Tags: android, cordova, emulation

I have created a android application using Cordova that calls the org.apache.cordova.file API.

My code appears to be working fine to create a file called "FooBar.txt" and write to it.

I say "working fine" in that i can step through the running code line by line and it runs correctly, doesn't error, but once the code has finished running in the AVD Android emulator i cant find any "FooBar.txt" file anywhere on my PC.

When running code through the AVD Android emulator, where should it be putting the file?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find your file in emulator you can use DDMS.
in eclipse: Window--> open perspective --> other --> DDMS --> in the "File Explorer" tab you can easily browse files.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an Android emulator, which is a virtual machine. When you are creating/extracting a file using your emulator, the file will land in your virtual computer. Try out comments, like

```
1. adb shell (a # prompt opens)
2. ls
3. cd /data/data
```